# n-dimensional array reduction to 2-d array with additional columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n-dim array in numpy and I have n column vectors.
I need to convert the n-dim array to a 2-D numpy array having

`rows = size of n-dim array`

`cols = n + 1`

to simplify with an example,

```
a = np.random.randint(50, size=(2,2))
r = np.array([0.2,1.9])
c = np.array([4,5])
a =>
array([[45, 18], [ 4, 24]])
c => array([4, 5])
r => array([ 0.2,  1.9])
```

I need to convert this to the following,

```
array([[ 45. ,   4. ,   0.2],
   [ 18. ,   5. ,   0.2],
   [  4. ,   4. ,   1.9],
   [ 24. ,   5. ,   1.9]])
```

I wrote it as follows, although my feeling is that it's not the best solution,
But it does work and seems fast enough for relatively large values,

```
def get_2d_array(  arr, r, c):
    w = None
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        rv = np.full((arr[i].shape[0], 1), r[i])
        z = np.concatenate((arr[i].reshape(-1, 1), c.reshape(-1, 1), rv), axis=1)
        if w is None:
            w = z
        else:
            w = np.concatenate((w, z))
    return w
```

Is there any other way of doing this in numpy without a loop?

Also, to generalize this, I actually have a 4-D array which I need to reduce to 2D array with similar construct as above. I couldn't get a recursive function to work and ended up have to reduce both 4th and 3rd dims explicitly as follows,

```
    def reduce_3d(self, arr3, row, col, third_dim_array):
    x = None
    for i in range(arr3.shape[0]):
        x1 = self.reduce_2d(arr3[i], row, col)
        third_array = np.full((x1.shape[0], 1), third_dim_array[i])
        x1 = np.concatenate((x1, third_array), axis=1)
        if x is None:
            x = x1
        else:
            x = np.concatenate((x, x1))
    return x

    def reduce_4d(air_temp ,row, col, third, second):
    w = None
    for j in range(air_temp.shape[0]):
        w1 = self.reduce_3d(air_temp[j], row, col, third)
        second_arr = np.full((w1.shape[0], 1), second[j])
        w1 = np.concatenate((w1, second_arr), axis=1)
        if w is None:
            w = w1
        else:
            w = np.concatenate((w, w1))
    return w
```

Output of a 4-D example is as follows,

```
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(2,3,2,2))
array([[[[ 8, 38],
     [89, 95]],
    [[63, 82],
     [24, 27]],
    [[22, 18],
     [25, 30]]],
   [[[94, 21],
     [83,  9]],
    [[25, 98],
     [84, 57]],
    [[89, 20],
     [40, 60]]]])

r   Out[371]: array([ 0.2,  1.9])
c   Out[372]: array([4, 5])
third array([ 50, 100, 150])
second array([[datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)]], dtype=object)

z = reduce_4d(a,r,c,third,second)
z

array([[8.0, 4.0, 0.2, 50.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [38.0, 5.0, 0.2, 50.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [89.0, 4.0, 1.9, 50.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [95.0, 5.0, 1.9, 50.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [63.0, 4.0, 0.2, 100.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [82.0, 5.0, 0.2, 100.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [24.0, 4.0, 1.9, 100.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [27.0, 5.0, 1.9, 100.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [22.0, 4.0, 0.2, 150.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [18.0, 5.0, 0.2, 150.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [25.0, 4.0, 1.9, 150.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [30.0, 5.0, 1.9, 150.0, datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)],
   [94.0, 4.0, 0.2, 50.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [21.0, 5.0, 0.2, 50.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [83.0, 4.0, 1.9, 50.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [9.0, 5.0, 1.9, 50.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [25.0, 4.0, 0.2, 100.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [98.0, 5.0, 0.2, 100.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [84.0, 4.0, 1.9, 100.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [57.0, 5.0, 1.9, 100.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [89.0, 4.0, 0.2, 150.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [20.0, 5.0, 0.2, 150.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [40.0, 4.0, 1.9, 150.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)],
   [60.0, 5.0, 1.9, 150.0, datetime.date(2010, 5, 4)]], dtype=object)

z.shape ==> (24L, 5L)
z.size => 120
a.size ==> 24

z.shape[0] == a.size
a.shape[1] == a.ndim + 1
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Thank you much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `np.meshgrid` to create the column combinations and stacks it together using `np.vstack`:

```
In [101]: a = np.array([[45, 18], [ 4, 24]])

In [102]: col_vecs = [np.array([4, 5]), np.array([0.2, 1.9])]

In [103]: np.vstack([np.ravel(a)] + [c.ravel() for c in np.meshgrid(*col_vecs)]).T
Out[103]: 
array([[45. ,  4. ,  0.2],
       [18. ,  5. ,  0.2],
       [ 4. ,  4. ,  1.9],
       [24. ,  5. ,  1.9]])
```

This should work for higher dimensions as well

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon another less convoluted approach and just mentioning it here,
please correct or add other options... thanks

```
def reduce( a, dims):
    """
    iterate over the dimensions of the array and 
     progressive build the columns through a combination of
    `tile` and `repeat`
    :param a: the input array of multi-dimensions
    :param dims: an array of feature vectors of size (n,) 
     in order of last one first.
    i.e. the first element of this array is an np array that matches or 
    corresponds to the last dimension in a
    :return: 
    """
    item_count = a.size
    m_all = a.reshape((-1, 1))
    repeat_cnt = 1
    level = 0
    for i in range(a.ndim):
        if level == 0:
            repeat_cnt = 1
            level = -1
        else:
            repeat_cnt = a.shape[level] * repeat_cnt
            level = level - 1
        cur_array = dims[i]
        tile_cnt = item_count / (cur_array.size * repeat_cnt)
        cur_col = np.tile(np.repeat(cur_array, repeat_cnt), tile_cnt).reshape((-1, 1))
        m_all = np.concatenate((m_all, cur_col), axis=1)
    return m_all
```